# pip don't work when installing (keep connecting back)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i had a problem for two days now about Pip giving out an error that i could not find an answer to it.

```
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after             
connection broken by.
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036CE750>, 'Connection to 192.168.0.8 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/six/
```

it seem it connect back to my machine (192.168.0.8) when installing the package, if anyone could tell me how to fix it, and why it is happening, then I would be thankful.

edit:

this error is outputed:

> Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
>   No cache entry available
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
>   There was an error checking the latest version of pip
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\musa\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
>       (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
>     File "c:\users\musa\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
>       raise err
>     File "c:\users\musa\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa)
>   socket.timeout: timed out

-flying-8lack

Comment: Proxy? Bad pip configuration? Hard to say without any details. Add a full output of pip with `-vv`.

Comment: @klaus-d No, I don't use a proxy."Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
No cache entry available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to say based on the description you have provided. However, I recommend you to install the anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/

This comes with the bundle of library and package managers, it comes with pip as well, so you don't have to install it separately. 
I hope there should be some trivial mistake while your installing pip, however now by installing anaconda I guess your problem will be solved.